# Finding the semantics of webpage content

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, semantics

I need to find the semantics of text in webpages.
i.e finding out if a webpage content is a poem or a conversation or an essay, etc
I could sense that this could be done using machine learning and natural language processing. It will be helpful if someone could provide more information about the techniques that could be followed as well as reference to some research paper.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at line/sentence lengths. They prove to be rather useful features for such a classification task.

You could train a classifier (eg. a decision tree or random forest) if you have access to enough labeled texts, by extracting features (number of words, average number of words per line and per sentence, total length etc.) and letting the classification algorithm do the rest.